# how to populate Struts 2 UI select tag?

Tags: select, tags, struts2

How can I populate Struts 2 UI select tag?

I keep getting the error:

tag `select`, field `list`: The requested list key `roles` could not be resolved as a `collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator` type.

Comment: Please post your code showing the action class getters and setters and population of the roles list that you are trying to use.

Comment: Is roles being obtained using ORM from a DB?... Please show the full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely that would be if your list roles is not initialized ( null ) . 
Or another reason can be if you have not declared an appropriate getter .